# Azure Postgres and Data Factory - Firewall Rules

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-virtual-network, azure-postgresql

I have an Azure Postgres database, and am looking to query it in an Azure Data Factory pipeline. When I go to add the database as a linked service, I see it fails as the IP address is not whitelisted. Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview#discover-service-tags-by-using-downloadable-json-files , I see that there's a whole lot of IPs in the region for Sql. I was wondering if there's some other way to allow Data Factory to read from the postgres database without enabling the button that allows all subscriptions (not even mine) network access to the database. Ideally, I'd like to say "allow all connections from this azure subscription". Is this doable?

Comment: Did you try  add the access roles for the Data Factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try add the access role for the Data Factory:
[image]

Grant the Data Factory one of bellow roles:

- **Contributor**: Grants full access to manage all resources, but does not
  allow you to assign roles in Azure RBAC.
- **Reader**: View all resources, but does not allow you to make any
  changes.

usually, there are only the tree ways to control the access: 1. add IP roles, 2. Allow access Azure. 3.Access control(IAM). If the IAM doesn't work, we only can add the IP or allow access from Azure.

For all the Azure Database(as I know), the only thing we can set to achieve your request is "Allow access to Azure Service":

[image]

HTH.

Comment: Is there a standard user or principal that data factory uses? Where does dfleon come from above? Or can I specify a user that the data factory will run as?

Comment: @ashic of course you can. You can select your AD user for the Postgre database. dfleon is my data factory name and just an example.

Comment: So when I go to add an Azure Database for Postgres linked service, I need to specify the database, username, password, port, etc. When I go to test connection, I see that it complains about the ip not being in the postgres db's allowed list. That's the issue - the ip rule.

Comment: @ashic I know your meaning, that why I want you test add the data factory role fro the postgres database. That's one of the way. If it doesn't work, we would say it's impossible for your question.

Comment: Hi @ashic, did you get any progresses now?

Comment: No... didn't work... can add the individual ips or allow access from any azure sub.

Comment: @ashic, usually, there are only the tree ways to control the access: 1. add IP roles, 2. Allow access Azure. 3.Access control(IAM). If the IAM doesn't work, we only can add the IP or allow access from Azure.

Comment: @ashic Did you set "Allow access to Azure Service" to YES ?

Comment: I ended up doing that, but would have preferred it to be limited to only our subscription. I guess that's not possible.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Thanks for marking and have a good day!