# Linked Service on Azure Data Factory V2 (on active directory 1) to an Azure PostgreSQL server (on active directory 2)

Tags: connection-string, azure-data-factory, postgresql-13, linked-service

I'm trying to create a linked service on Azure Data Factory V2 (from my personal subscription) to an Azure PostgreSQL database hosted by company A (on a different active directory and subscription).

- I have already made sure that the "Allow access to Azure Services" is
  enabled on the Company A's server (as mentioned in the threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64140858/azure-postgres-and-data-factory-firewall-rules))
- I have also whitelisted the IP address of the Azure Integration Runtime on Company A's server.
- I can already successfully make SQL queries to Company A's DB using my DB query software + PostgreSQL 13.5 driver (on local machine ofcourse)
- It is important to use the linked service type of "Azure Database for PostgreSQL" because the connection will be used as a source in Data Flows feature.
  [list of linked services tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO5Qo.png)
- The linked service type of a generic "PostgreSQL" also works!!! But not usable as a source in Data Flows which is my objective.
- This is the error I receive when testing the connection, even though the exact same credentials work on all other ways of making sql queries. [Error window on testing connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG0sp.png)
- btw SSL encryption without verification is what is supposed to work according the db admin.

Suggestions and further questions are more than welcome!
It's my first time asking a question, so tips on better describing problems are also welcome :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "validate server cert"?
What's your connection string look link in Azure Portal?

[image]